# LinearLayout is only allowing one view to be added

Tags: android, android-layout

```
  layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           btn.setText("button");

            layout.addView(btn);

            Button btn1 = new Button(this);
            btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           btn1.setText("button");

            layout.addView(btn1);
```

I know I must be missing something because whenever I add views to this layout I only have one of them show up.

Comment: y don't u try adding buttons through xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enjoy buddy

```
layout = new LinearLayout(this); 
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
setContentView(layout);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Reome this `addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

You have not set Oreientation , Default is Horizontal, and you have given  width `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT`

Answer (score 1):

```
 layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout .setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); // orientation vertical try  this

            addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           btn.setText("button");

            layout.addView(btn);

            Button btn1 = new Button(this);
            btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           btn1.setText("button");

            layout.addView(btn1);
```

Answer (score 1):

orientation of your linear layout must be horizontal. change it to vertical